# SQL select row count and Id value of multiple rows with equal values

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by

We have this table for products on a store with values like this:

```
Id   Name       PartNumber   Param1    Param2    Param3   Stock   Active
--   ---------  ----------   ------    ------    ------   -----   ------
1    BoxA1      10000        20        A         B        4       1
2    BoxA1      10000.a      20        A         B        309     1
3    CabinetZ2  30000        40        B         C        0       0
4    CabinetZ2  30000.b      40        B         C        1098    1
5    BoxA1      10000.c      20        A         B        15      1
```

As you can see there are Products with identical name and params but different Id and part number.

Products with Id's 1, 2 and 5 have identical name and param values.

We need to disable identical param products based on stock so we have only the product with more stock active out of those with identical params.

The result should be like this:

```
Id   Name       PartNumber   Param1    Param2    Param3   Stock   Active
--   ---------  ----------   ------    ------    ------   -----   ------
1    BoxA1      10000        20        A         B        4       0      <- Not active
2    BoxA1      10000.a      20        A         B        309     1      <- Active 
3    CabinetZ2  30000        40        B         C        0       0
4    CabinetZ2  30000.b      40        B         C        1098    1
5    BoxA1      10000.c      20        A         B        15      0      <- Not active
```

This process is required because we are receiving stock quantities from an external source (webservice) several times per day and after each stock update we need to evaluate which should remain active.

What we do at this moment and works ok but does not have a good performance is use a stored procedure that does the following:

```
DECLARE product_list CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL FOR
  SELECT Id, Name, PartNumber, Param1, Param2, Param3, Stock 
  FROM Products
  ORDER BY Name, Param1, Param2, Param3, Stock DESC

OPEN product_list

FETCH NEXT FROM product_list INTO @OldId, @OldName, @OldPartNumber, @OldParam1, @OldParam2, @OldParam3, @OldStock

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
BEGIN

    (Compare all rows and perform updates to disable the ones with less stock)

    FETCH NEXT FROM product_list INTO @OldId, @OldName, @OldPartNumber, @OldParam1, @OldParam2, @OldParam3, @OldStock

END
CLOSE product_list
```

Found this type of query using OVER (PARTITION BY) and we are very close of our objective of making this more efficient:

```
SELECT Id, Name, PartNumber, Param1, Param2, Param3, Stock, Active,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Param1, Param2, Param3 ORDER BY stock DESC) AS Items
FROM Products
```

With the following result:

```
Id   Name       PartNumber   Param1    Param2    Param3   Stock   Items
--   ---------  ----------   ------    ------    ------   -----   ------
1    BoxA1      10000        20        A         B        4       3
3    CabinetZ2  30000        40        B         C        0       2
```

The problem is that we are getting the first Id found and not the Id of the one with more stock.

We are expecting a result like this but can't find the way to fix this query or a workaround:

```
Id   Name       PartNumber   Param1    Param2    Param3   Stock   Items
--   ---------  ----------   ------    ------    ------   -----   ------
2    BoxA1      10000.a      20        A         B        309     3
4    CabinetZ2  30000.b      40        B         C        1098    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use RANK function in sql server and order it in desc, see the below code:

```
select Id,
    name,
    partnumber,
    param1,
    param2,
    param3, 
    stock,
    active 
    from (
        select *, 
            RANK() (parition by id, param1, param2, param3 order by stock desc) as max_stock 
            from product)x
        where max_stock = 1
```

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a charm. Just one precision, You missed the OVER after RANK().

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH t AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Param1, Param2, Param3 ORDER BY stock DESC) i,* FROM Products)
UPDATE t
SET Active = CASE i WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

There was one ambiguity in your question: if two ids have the same # in stock, are they both active, or just one? If only one, what determines the priority?

If you want both to be active:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT MAX(stock) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Param1, Param2, Param3) max_stock,* FROM Products)
UPDATE t
SET Active = CASE WHEN stock = max_stock THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is what you're looking for. I'm not sure why you'd need rownumber()

```
SELECT * FROM Products p1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Name, PartNumber, MAX(Stock) AS MaxStock
FROM Products
GROUP BY Name, PartNumber) AS p2
ON p1.Name = p2.Name AND p1.PartNumber = p2.PartNumber AND p1.Stock = p2.MaxStock;
```